# How to mock a javascript function in react

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking

custom.js file:

```js
    let cnclient;
    document.addEventListener("DOMLoaded", function (event) {
       onReady();
    });
    onReady = (function () {
       testAPI= new TestAPI(
          "*", 
          {
              "eventHandlers": [
                  { "event": "onLoad", "callback": loadAuth },
              ]
          }, 
          true
       );
    }
    function loadAuth() {
       function(auth){
           window.sessionStorage.setItem('token', auth.ptoken);
       } 
    }
    onReady.prototype.refreshToken = () =>{
        let newT;
        cnclient.post({"request" : "refreshT"}, function(data) {  
            window.sessionStorage.setItem('token', auth.ptoken);
        });
        return newT;
    }
```

Calling custom.js in React to get a new token and calling the `refreshToken` function to get a new token. it is working fine but unable write the unit test.

TestLoad.jsx file:

```
    //importing custom.js fil`your text`
    export const useTestLoad = ()=> {
        let OnReadyConstructor = new onReady(); //here giving error while mocking
        OnReadyConstructor.refreshToken(); 
    };
```

Spent couple of times to mock it but giving error.

Error:

> TypeError: _custom.onReady is not a constructor

I tried to mock it but giving the error:

```js
  jest.mock('../custom', () => {
       return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
       return { refreshToken: jest.fn() };
     });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

To mock a JavaScript function in React, you can use a testing library like Jest and a mocking library like **jest.mock**. Here's how you can mock the **onReady** function in your example:

1- Create a file called **custom.js** in your test directory (e.g., **src/**mocks**/custom.js**) with the following content:

```
// Mocking custom.js

let cnclient;
const onReady = jest.fn().mockImplementation(function () {
  testAPI = new TestAPI("*", {
    eventHandlers: [{ event: "onLoad", callback: loadAuth }],
  }, true);
});

function loadAuth() {
  function (auth) {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("token", auth.ptoken);
  }
}

onReady.prototype.refreshToken = () => {
  let newT;
  cnclient.post({ request: "refreshT" }, function (data) {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("token", auth.ptoken);
  });
  return newT;
};

export default { onReady };
```

In your test file, import the mocked custom.js module and use **jest.mock** to mock the entire module. Update your **TestLoad.jsx** file to the following:

```
import custom from './custom';

jest.mock('./custom'); // Mock the custom.js module

export const useTestLoad = () => {
  const OnReadyConstructor = new custom.onReady(); // Use the mocked onReady constructor
  OnReadyConstructor.refreshToken();
};
```

By mocking the **custom.js** module, you can now control the behavior of the onReady function and its methods during testing.

Comment: Your seven answers this month appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.